# Shell script output formatting

Tags: shell, scripting, text-formatting

I have a file in below format -

```
root            0       system          0  
                        bin             2
                        sys             3
                        security        7
                        cron            8
                        audit           10
                        lp              11
daemon          1       staff           1  
bin             2       bin             2  
                        sys             3
                        adm             4
sys             3       sys             3
```

And want to convert it into new file with format using shell script -

```
root            system,bin,sys,security,cron,audit,lp
daemon          staff
bin             bin,sys,adm
sys             sys
```

Comment: I strongly suggest taking a peek at the [formatting options available to posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) especially with inputs that have column-exact indentations...

Comment: Which shell do you want to do this in (bash, pure sh, ksh, etc)?  Does it have to be done by the shell itself, or will you consider solutions using other common unix tools?

Comment: I would like to use ksh.

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box, an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NF==4 && NR>1 {printf "\n" ; } 
     NF==4 { printf "%-10s %s",$1,$3} 
     NF==2 { printf ",%s",$1} 
     END   { printf "\n" ; } '
```

where

- `NF` is Number of Field (column number),
- `NR` is Number of Record (line number),
- various conditions selects what to print,
- `printf` does not print trailing new line.

Comment: Thank you.But it is working only for 1st entry i.e. ,bin,sys,security,cron,audit,lp,sys,adm is the output

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane '
   if ( @F == 4 ) {                 # num fields are 4
      print $result if $. > 1;      # in case we"re not @ BOF, show result
      $result = join "\t", @F[0,2]; # initialize result
   } else {
      $result .= ",$F[0]";          # append result
   }
   eof && print $result;            # on the last line, show result
' filename
```

Comment: Thank you.But is not working as expected.

Comment: With this code it is giving output comma separated values for column -

Comment: ,root,bin,sys,security,cron,audit,lp,daemon,bin,sys,adm,sys,adm,uucp,invscout

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0pe 's/\h+\d+\h*\n\h+/,/g;  s/\h+\d+//g' ex
```

- first substitution replaces numbers followed by `\n...spaces`  by `,`
- second substitution removes the other numbers.